# I don't understand my installation of Python via Homebrew

Tags: python, homebrew

I have just installed Python using Homebrew.  I used the command `brew install python` (after installing XQuartz, which is a prerequisite).

This page - https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python - tells me the following:

> **Issues**
>
> Assuming a standard Homebrew install, the Prefix will be
>   `/usr/local` and the Cellar will be `/usr/local/Cellar`.
>
> Homebrew installs Python to the Cellar, using the standard `./configure
>   --prefix=#{prefix}`.
>
> This sets up:
>
> - the "site-packages" folder as
>     `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.
> - the "install-scripts" folder as `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/bin`.
>
> If site-packages lives in Python's Cellar, then user installed packages
>   will be wiped between Python updates. Same for install-scripts, with
>   the added problem that users have to manually add Python's cellar bin
>   folder to the path.
>
> **Solution**
>
> Homebrew performs two actions on install to address these
>   issues.
>
> - First, the Cellar site-packages folder is removed, and a symlink to
>     `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` in the Prefix is created. This
>     will allow site-packages to persist between Python updates, as
>     Homebrew has special handling for some languages that use lib for
>     user-installable libraries.
> - Second, a `distutils.cfg` file is written to set the install-scripts
>     folder to `/usr/local/share/python`. Users can add
>     `/usr/local/share/python` to the `PATH` to pick up installed scripts.

***What I don't understand is the line that read "the Cellar site-packages folder is removed, and a symlink to
`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` in the Prefix is created."  When I look in "the prefix" -- which I understand is '/usr/local' -- I don't see a symlink.  Where is this symlink that is being referred to?***

One of the reasons I am confused is that when I run `pip install virtualenvwrapper` I get output that tells me: "Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)".  I don't understand where this `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` directory is coming from and why it ever gets referred to.

Having said that, `pip install virtualenvwrapper` does seem to finish without a problem and doesn't require sudo, which I think is supposed to be one of the advantages of installations that use Homebrew.  The entire output of `pip install virtualenvwrapper` is:

```
Downloading/unpacking virtualenvwrapper
  Running setup.py egg_info for package virtualenvwrapper

Downloading/unpacking virtualenv (from virtualenvwrapper)
  Downloading virtualenv-1.8.2.tar.gz (2.2MB): 2.2MB downloaded
  Storing download in cache at ./Library/Caches/pip-downloads/http%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpackages%2Fsource%2Fv%2Fvirtualenv%2Fvirtualenv-1.8.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package virtualenv

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_templates'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv-clone in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stevedore in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): distribute in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg (from stevedore->virtualenvwrapper)
Installing collected packages: virtualenvwrapper, virtualenv
  Running setup.py install for virtualenvwrapper

    Skipping installation of /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/__init__.py (namespace package)
    Installing /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper-3.6-py2.7-nspkg.pth
    changing mode of /usr/local/share/python/virtualenvwrapper.sh to 755
    changing mode of /usr/local/share/python/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh to 755
  Running setup.py install for virtualenv

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_templates'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
    Installing virtualenv script to /usr/local/share/python
    Installing virtualenv-2.7 script to /usr/local/share/python
Successfully installed virtualenvwrapper virtualenv
Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 0):

[From the updated documentation:](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Homebrew-and-Python.md)

> for Python 2.7.x, you'll find it at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.
>
> Python 2.7 also searches for modules in:
>
> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
>
> ~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages

So, you likely had an echo of a previously installed package in /Library/Python2:7/site-packages

Homebrew recently hit 1.0, a lot has changed since you asked the question.